# C# EventViewer Logs Parsing

Tags: c#, logging, event-viewer

I am in charge of parsing forwarded EventViewer (evt) logs (Windows 7?). To do this I am run a query using Log Parser 2.2 over the logs and pulling out specific EventIDs and writing these to a CSV file. However, I am considering using [EventViewerReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogreader.aspx) to do this instead.

The query I am doing on these evt includes a "strings" column which outputs a bunch of junk usually of the format: [SID](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems)|Username|Usergroup|... but it isn't consistent. What I want is a consistent way to get the username for these events and filter out the useless data. The problem is that I don't understand the format for the output. I am wondering if these events have a standard format or if this is a custom format from my work? The method I have right now basically looks for known usergroups and checks for potential usernames to the left of them (skipping "LOCALS SERVICE", "NETWORK SERVICE", "-", and some other keywords). My issue with this method is that I don't know all of the usergroups, and I can get false-positives on usernames.

Here are some of the [EventID Codes](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/default.aspx) I am looking at:
https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/quickref/downloads/quickref.zip

```
4624    An account was successfully logged on
4625    An account failed to log on
4647    User initiated logoff
4648    A logon was attempted using explicit credentials
4800    The workstation was locked
4801    The workstation was unlocked
4802    The screen saver was invoked
4803    The screen saver was dismissed
```

Comment: I ended up switching from Log Parser to EventViewerReader. This let me grab XML "strings" by name. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb671204(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/29babcd3-dea2-41f9-83bb-7da7abfa36aa/reading-event-logs-with-eventlogquery-amp-eventlogreader-eventinstanceformatdescription-not?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: https://blog.backslasher.net/filtering-windows-event-log-using-xpath.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up looking closer at the evt files and saw they have a set XML schema. "Strings" isn't really an element, but a the concatonated values of EventData child Data elements. All I did was look at the schema for each EventID and found the depth of the username in each event type.

I think it was strings[5] (TargetUserName) for logon/logoff, strings[0] for a couple others, and strings[1] for a couple more.

```
<EventData>
  <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-5-18</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectUserName">XXX-PC$</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">WORKGROUP</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x3e7</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetUserSid">S-1-5-18</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetUserName">SYSTEM</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetDomainName">NT AUTHORITY</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetLogonId">0x3e7</Data>
...
</EventData>
```